FTDI chip not working properly
I recently purchased an FTDI chip from AliExpress. However, every time I try to use it on Linux via the picocom command, it gives me a lot of unknown characters. I tried changing the baud rate, I tried fixing the wiring: ground to ground, Rx to Tx, Tx to Rx, 3.3 V to VCC.
I also tried Tx to Tx and Rx to Rx, but nothing worked. Then I changed the board I was trying to connect to UART on, and still, I got the same issues. I also discovered that my FTDI chip could power up the board without me turning the board on or even plugging it to the electricity, which seemed very weird. Also, when I touch or even move the wire connected to Rx on the FTDI, it prints a lot of unknown characters. So this got me thinking that it was a problem from the FTDI chip itself, what do you guys think.
First of all, I connected ground on the board (the board with the UART) to the FTDI's ground, 3.3 V to VCC, Rx to Tx, Tx to Rx. It gave me unknown characters. I tried all common baud rates, and many more uncommon ones, but nothing worked. I did all the steps right, but still nothing worked.
I switched Rx to Rx and Tx to Tx, also nothing worked. I changed the board with UART that I was working on, and I still got the same issue. The FTDI was printing random characters and unknown ones even when the board was off. Even if I hold the wire without touching the exposed end, it printed unknown characters. I also tried connecting ground only without the VCC, and it gave me the same output.

Can you include a schematic of how the FTDI serial module is connected to the "board"  which the FTDI chip is trying to communicate with.

Very possible your chip is defective, to the extent that it would have been able to "work" in the first place. Caveat emptor.

perform a loopback test

as jsotola said, do a loopback test, connect the FTDI TX to its RX, nothing else, then send and try to read data

I tried the loopback test, and it works. I used Putty for it, it opened a terminal and then i connected RX to TX on the FTDI, and whatever I type shows on the terminal. For good measure, I removed the RX and then nothing i typed showed on the terminal which confirms that the loopback test works. What should I do now.

Do you have an oscilloscope? If so, check the waveform at the chip's TX pin while you're transmitting a character repeatedly on the computer. You should be able to determine the baud rate and decode the signal by reading 0s and 1s manually. Capital U is a good choice since its binary code is 1010101 in ASCII.

No I don't have an oscilloscope unfortunately

All those weird things are normal if you use it wrong. And that is not an FTDI chip, it's a random UART module that uses an FTDI chip (big difference). You never tell where do you connect the FTDI module and what baud rate you use. If you do not have everything correct you will get garbage and also when touching the RX pin you will get garbage as the RX pin is only weakly pulled up so it receives mains hum. If you connect FTDI TX to FTDI RX it will likely act as a perfect loopback device.

"I recently purchased an FTDI chip from AliExpress". Buying on AliExpress is always a gamble. Sometimes you get something that works. Sometimes you don't.
